# Is there a name for a reflexive symmetric binary relation?

Tags: terminology, relations

I am interested in a relation which we know is only reflexive and symmetric. I can extend it transitively, but for now I want less structure, not more. However, it's pretty unwieldy to keep saying "reflexive and symmetric," so I was wondering if there was a given name.

More generally, a set of names for relations based on properties would be helpful as well.

Comment: That is called a graph.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Wikipedia article on equivalence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), that type of relation is called a [Dependency Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_relation) if you only have finitely many elements and a [Tolerance Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolerance_relation) if you have a possibly infinite number of elements. The section [Connection to other relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Connections_to_other_relations) on the equivalence relation page gives names for the other possible kinds of relations.